# How can I make the locally running GAE dev server auto-detect changes to templates?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mako

I notice that whenever I make a change to one of my gae project python files, my changes automatically impact my locally running development server. However, whenever I make a change to one of my Mako templates, google app engine does not automatically detect it, and I have to restart the local development server manually for the change to take effect. As you can imagine, this makes editing UI elements tedious. Is there any way I can make gae auto-detect changes to my templates?

Comment: I think this not depends on GAE but rather on the browser cache. If you open the same page in another browser which hasn't it in its cache the changes will appear without having to restart the dev server. So you should clear the browser cache and refresh the page.

Comment: When you create your Mako TemplateLookup, see the filesystem_checks parameter.

Comment: I am experiencing similar issues. I use jinja2 templates and I always have to load the page twice and sometimes stop the server even for native python code.

Comment: The paste HTTP server has a nice feature called the "reloader" that watches the filesystem and then restarts the server when one of the files changes; it even lets you configure exactly which files are and are not watched. Maybe gae supports something similar?